# Contact Form 7 : send default value to mail if textarea empty

Tags: php, wordpress, contact-form-7

[your-name] I have a contact form7 3.7 with a textarea field as :

```
<p>Message (optional)<br />
[textarea my-message]</p>
```

And Mail Format is :

```
From :    [your-name] | [your-email]
Message : [my-message]
```

Now, currently the textarea is empty.
if user does not fills any data in message box, the mail is sent with empty field.
How to send "None" value by default if the textarea is empty ?

Comment: Check the values for [my-message], if you can. If its blank, then assign some value to [my-message]

Comment: Thanks Sushil, I tried adding a check/filter with $_POST[$name] = "None"; //If Empty. But adding this crashed the entire page

Comment: May be syntax error in $_POST[$name]. Try to use $_POST["name_of_textfield"]. Or there may be other way to read post values in Contact Form 7.

Comment: I finally got $_POST[$name] to work. But the field is empty in the mail. While on inspect element it has value : "None"

Comment: Then either variable is not assigned properly to  [my-message] or your variable is overwritten somewhere. Go through properly through code, some hidden magic will be there.

Comment: thanks a lot.. working on it...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This took a while to find and could use some work yet, but try this in your `functions.php` file:

```
add_action("wpcf7_posted_data", "wpcf7_modify_this");
function wpcf7_modify_this($posted_data) {

    // if user leaves the message area blank, set to "None"
    if ($posted_data['my-message'] == "")
        $posted_data['my-message'] = "None";

    // generic example
    if ( /* some logic */ )
        $posted_data['/* cf7-field-name */'] = "ValueToEmail";

    return $posted_data;
}
```

One thing to note here is that validation occurs prior to this point, so if you're allowing users to enter a blank value, don't make it required.

Answer (score 0):

According to the Contact Form 7 Website you can specify default values.

Example:

```
[email* your-email default:user_email]
```

This will populate the field with the current users email address.

more information [here](http://contactform7.com/text-fields/)

Comment: Thanks Danyo, but setting a default value shows the same on the interface.

Answer (score 0):

It's so eassy.
Select **Textarea** option from **generate tag** dropdown menu in contactform form generation.
And there is option for set default value.
By using  that option you can set default value of textarea.
I Have attached one image here...
In that image i shown details.
[image: ContactForm7 Add new form]

Its work for me...
I hope that it's also work for you.

Comment: Thanks Bhavesh, but my requirement is to not to show the default value on the interface. But send to the mail if field is empty

Comment: if textarea is empty then send default value?

Comment: yes.. I created a filter for the same and inserted the value.. but it is not reaching in the mail

Answer (score 0):

I tried the code provided by @DACrosby above, but that one didn't work for me. So I deleted some code and changed it to this, and then it works perfectly!

```
add_action("wpcf7_posted_data", "wpcf7_modify_this");
function wpcf7_modify_this($posted_data) {

    // if user leaves the message area blank, set to "None"
    if ($posted_data['my-message'] == "")
        $posted_data['my-message'] = "None";

    // generic example
    if ( /* some logic */ )
        $posted_data['/* cf7-field-name */'] = "ValueToEmail";

    return $posted_data;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You can't do that with Contact Form 7 as far as I know.