# How to change text before sending in Wordpress - CF7

Tags: php, wordpress, contact-form-7

I have contact form on my website and want to change one thing. My contact form have checkboxes and I want to send different text than is in checkbox. For example: I have checkbox with text "Test" and I want to send in mail "11:30 Tested". I try to do that in so many ways, but it's not working and I don't know where is problem. I check "hidden fields", but when I don't check my checkbox, in mail I have this hidden text.

Next to I try this:

[solution from this forum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41955282/how-to-send-no-in-form-when-checkbox-isnt-checked-in-wordpress)

But I can't change my text, when checkbox is checked. When it is empty, this field send me "nej", but I want nothing :)

I saw this topic:

[cf7 before send](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40000543/modify-contact-form-7-submission-data)

If I have empty checkbox, cf7 send me text, like in hidden fields. Maybe this code can help me?

I have twenty checkboxes and I want to send different text from them, when they are checked. If not - I want to send nothing :)

Someone help me with this? Thanks so much!
Rafael

PS I use Contact Form 7 in Wordpress to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Contact Form 7 supports pipes ("|") as a separator of what users see and what is the actual value of the input. You can use it like that.

```
[checkbox* test_checkbox use_label_element “Test|11:30 Test” “Test 2|12:30 Test”]
```

Comment: Thanks for help. You save my weekend. Sometimes the simplest answer is the best and I don't think about it. ;)